# How do I determine which JList item is selected?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, listener, jlist

I want to have a certain bit of code run depending on which JList item has been clicked on.

But how do I determine which item has been selected?

Here is the code:

```
public void launchFrame() {
        String selection1 = "";
        String[]mainContents = {"Vehicles","Bikes/Bicycles","Boats","Houses","Businesses","Objects","Jobs","Ranks","Licenses"};
        String[]selectionVehicles = {};
        String[]selectionBikesBicycles = {};
        String[]selectionBoats = {};
        String[]selectionHouses = {};
        String[]selectionBusinesses = {};
        String[]selectionObjects = {};
        String[]selectionJobs = {};
        String[]selectionRanks = {};
        String[]selectionLicenses = {};
        JFrame f = new JFrame("MTG SAMP Server Reference");
        JList listAll = new JList(mainContents);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.pack();
        f.setSize(1200, 800);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.add(listAll);
        listAll.setSize(250, 250);
        listAll.setLocation(50, 50);
        switch (selection1) {
            case "Vehicles":
                JList listVehicles = new JList(mainContents);
                f.add(listVehicles);
                listVehicles.setSize(250, 250);
                listVehicles.setLocation(350, 50);
                f.repaint();
                f.revalidate();
                break;
            case "Bikes/Bicycles":
                JList listBikesBicycles = new JList(mainContents);
                f.add(listBikesBicycles);
                listBikesBicycles.setSize(250, 250);
                listBikesBicycles.setLocation(350, 50);
                f.repaint();
                f.revalidate();
                break;
            case "Boats":
                JList listBoats = new JList(mainContents);
                f.add(listBoats);
                listBoats.setSize(250, 250);
                listBoats.setLocation(350, 50);
                f.repaint();
                f.revalidate();
                break;
            case "Houses":
                JList listHouses = new JList(mainContents);
                f.add(listHouses);
                listHouses.setSize(250, 250);
                listHouses.setLocation(350, 50);
                f.repaint();
                f.revalidate();
                break;
            case "Businesses":
                JList listBusinesses = new JList(mainContents);
                f.add(listBusinesses);
                listBusinesses.setSize(250, 250);
                listBusinesses.setLocation(350, 50);
                f.repaint();
                f.revalidate();
                break;
            case "Objects":
                JList listObjects = new JList(mainContents);
                f.add(listObjects);
                listObjects.setSize(250, 250);
                listObjects.setLocation(350, 50);
                f.repaint();
                f.revalidate();
                break;
            case "Jobs":
                JList listJobs = new JList(mainContents);
                f.add(listJobs);
                listJobs.setSize(250, 250);
                listJobs.setLocation(350, 50);
                f.repaint();
                f.revalidate();
                break;
            case "Ranks":
                JList listRanks = new JList(mainContents);
                f.add(listRanks);
                listRanks.setSize(250, 250);
                listRanks.setLocation(350, 50);
                f.repaint();
                f.revalidate();
                break;
            case "Licenses":
                JList listLicenses = new JList(mainContents);
                f.add(listLicenses);
                listLicenses.setSize(250, 250);
                listLicenses.setLocation(350, 50);
                f.repaint();
                f.revalidate();
                break;
        }
            Container contentPaneMain = f.getContentPane();
            contentPaneMain.add(new MTGSAMPServerReference());
        }
```

Each set of text in the quotes represents a separate item.

So if "Vehicles" is clicked, how do I get it to set `selection1` to `"Vehicles"`?

Comment: You already add an answer to this almost exact same question, and accepted it. Why do you ask it once again?

Comment: Makes no sense to re-ask. Voting to close this question.

Comment: The other question was only a partial answer. If I still have questions, why shouldn't I continue to ask?

Comment: @JBNizet and HovercraftFullOfEels, UsabilityOrDie seems to have the right answer. This is why re-asking questions can be helpful. Not always wise to judge before having knowledge of a situation. Consider giving things a chance before just shooting them down. Not helpful to shoot people's questions down as that is exactly what this site is intended for. Please reconsider your actions next time!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using Java 7 (if earlier you will not be able to use strings inside switch statements):

```
selection1 = (String)listAll.getSelectedValue();
```

Comment: Yes, I am using Java 7. This looks like what I need, and I will try it! Thanks!